# Prove : Each distinct $R_{k,e}$ can appear maximum $\sqrt b \leq n^{3}$ times.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinations, coloring, extremal-combinatorics

**Notation:**
$H$  is the  adjacency matrix of graph $H'$ respectively. $H_k$ is the  block or sub-matrix of matrix $H$. The adjacency matrix of graph $H_k \cup  H_e$ (subgraphs of $H'$) is $M_{(k,e)}$ where   $M_{(k,e)} =\left( \begin{array}{ccc} H_e & R_{k,e} \\ R_{k,e}^{T} & H_k\\ \end{array} \right) $,  where, $R_{k,e}$ is the non symmetric sub-matrix of adjacency matrix $H$.  Here, $R_{k,e}$ represents  edges  between $H_k,  H_e$.   The matrix $H$ looks like-
$$H = \begin{bmatrix}
H_{(x)} & R_{(x, x-1)} & R_{(x,x-2)} & \dots & \dots & R_{(x,1)} \\
R_{(x,x-1)^{T}} & H_{(x-1)} & R_{(x-1,x-2)} & \dots & \dots & R_{(x-1,1)} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
R_{(x,1)^{T}} & R_{(x-1,1)^{T}} & R_{(x-2,1)^{T}} & \dots & \dots &H_{1} \end{bmatrix}$$.

**Facts:**
Each $M_{k,e}$ can have exactly $6$ vertices, $3$ vertices in $H_k$ and $3$ vertices in $H_e$. So, $R_{k,e}$ is a non-symmetric matrix of dimension $3 \times 3$ .

It is clear that each distinct $R_{k,e}$ can appear maximum $b$ times where $b \leq n^{9}$, since there are maximum $n^{3}$ different possible $H_k$  and $n^{3}$ different possible $H_e$ .

**Problem:** I want to **prove** that-

Each distinct $R_{k,e}$ can appear maximum $\sqrt b \leq n^{3}$ times.

I am assuming  the statement is correct.

Comment: MathOverflow copy of the question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/241557/sqrt-b-leq-n3-possible-number-of-repetitions-of-a-submatrix-r-k-e If you are posting the same question to multiple sites, you should add a link. See [this post on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) (and maybe also some other posts on meta about [meta-tag:cross-posting]).

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong statement. $ \sqrt b \geq n^{3}$ whatever way you try.